# How can i upload file inside specific node of the tree view while my tree view has dynamically made from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the upload page the there will be some drop down list based on the treeview node and upload control, so after select the item from dropdwon list and by clicking the submit button the file should be uploaded on that specific location.

Comment: Sorry i mean upload file on the specific node in treeview based on the above condition.When the treeview made dynamically from database. Thank you once again

Comment: Welocome to Stackoverflow. Show your code and it will help to answer your question clearer.